# PHP using imagecreatefromstring to convert an SVG string to image

Tags: javascript, php, svg

The following javascript code will convert an SVG string into a image blob that can then be used to display in a browser:

```
 var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="390" height="65">' +
        '<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#7890A7" stroke-width="20" stroke="#ffffff" ></rect>' +
        '<foreignObject x="15" y="10" width="100%" height="100%">' +
        '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
        ' <em>I</em> am' +
        '<span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 20px #000000;">' +
        ' HTML in SVG!</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</foreignObject>' +
        '</svg>';

    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
```

The trouble is that i want to be able to do this same thing but in PHP. I thought about using the `imagecreatefromstring` function. Is that the right way to go about it?

Comment: did you find a solution about this? I'm trying to send the SVG to the server and transform that into PNG

Comment: @SolidSnake unfortunately not. We ended up using the Javascript implementation. You may have to find a 3rd party library as the inbuilt `imagecreatefromstring` doesnt support svg

Comment: I ended up using Inkscape to convert the SVG to PNG as all of the other libraries/extensions failed to show a correct converted image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PHP manual for `imagecreatefromstring` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

> imagecreatefromstring() returns an image identifier representing the
>   image obtained from the given image. These types will be automatically
>   detected if your build of PHP supports them: JPEG, PNG, GIF, WBMP, and
>   GD2.

SVG doesn't appear anywhere in the linked page.